# php str_replace static to a dynamic id

Tags: php, string, replace

I have the following code:

```
<strong>this is test1 </strong>
<strong>this is test2 </strong>
<strong>this is test3 </strong>
<strong>this is test4 </strong>
```

and I need to change that to:

```
<div id="test1"><strong>this is test1 </strong></div>
<div id="test2"><strong>this is test2 </strong></div>
<div id="test3"><strong>this is test3 </strong></div>
```

with str_replace or something... Any ideas? As the text is coming from CMS. I need to have ids for this text to move to the subsection when the menu item is clicked.

Comment: not understandable at all. please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "when the menu item is clicked" - why PHP, not javascript? I suppose, you need to change the html fragment on the fly

Comment: Yes Iam actually generating menu dynamically with the list of headings and subheadings on a page. Iam creating the menu and on clicking the element I need to go to the respective subheading so I need to add an id for a div element. this is what Iam trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {

$test$i = str_replace('<strong>','<div id="test'.$i.'"><strong>',
    '<strong>this is test'.$i.'</strong>');

$test$i = str_replace('</strong>','</strong></div>',
    $test$i);

}
```

You'll now have $test1, $test2, $test3 and $test4.

Edit:
Note that PHP is serverside and you'll have to reload the page to execute PHP code.

EDIT: New code:

```
$text = '<strong>this is a test</strong><strong>this is a test</strong>';

function str_replacef($from, $to, $subject)
{
    $from = '/'.preg_quote($from, '/').'/';

    return preg_replace($from, $to, $subject, 1);
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
$text = str_replacef('<strong>','<div id="'.$i.'"><strong2>',$text);
$text = str_replacef('</strong>','</strong2></div>',$text);
}

$text = str_replace('<strong2>','<strong>',$text);
$text = str_replace('</strong2>','</strong>',$text);

echo $text;
```

Comment: I have tried this and this always displaying <div id="test4"><strong> since str_replace is doing a full replace for each iteration

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I don't understand

Comment: So the `this is test4` gets removed?

Comment: I see your edit now... So you get <div id="text4"><strong>this is test4</strong></div> 4 times?

Comment: No Iam getting that just once

Comment: If it is in a loop yes it is displaying 4 times

Comment: Yes and that is the code he gave you. A loop. Why did you change it?

Comment: I should not display it 4 times. I want the text replaced in the string and should be displayed outside the loop

Comment: Is there any way in php that the string replace is done in only forward and not backward

Comment: What? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Björn Schönrock https://3v4l.org/TEGLD .. This is exactly wht IAm tying to do.. Chec that

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: So you want output <div id="test1"><strong>this is test</strong></div><div id="test2"><strong>this is test</strong></div> ?

Comment: YES exactly. IS there a way to do that ??

Comment: Yes there is. I'll edit my answer in a few minutes. Please be patient.

Comment: @user1384817 I've edited my code. I hope this is what you want. If it is, could you please accept my answer? We'll both get reputation for it.

Comment: @user1384817 Yes I did. Is my code above what you wanted? If so, please accept my answer...

Comment: The echo in the for loop is displaying 4 times... Which is a repetition of my text. so that wouldn't solve my issue. IF the print statement is outside the loop the div id is always 4

Comment: Pfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff. You could have said that earlier.

Comment: Ok here are the details.. I have a long text which has headings and subheadings... I have generated a Menu for this taking out the text between <strong> </strong> tags in my text. Now when I click on this menu item user should go to that subheading right??  For this Iam adding <div> tag with ID. So that my menu item could be <a href="#item1"> item </a> <a href="#item2"> item </a> and my text would be <strong><div id="item1">item</div></strong> and that should work ...

Comment: Björn Schönrock... That was great piece of code and it worked. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can also use preg_replace.

I'm typing on my phone at work, but something like this and the for loop from Björns answer will do it.

```
preg_replace("/(<strong>.*<\/strong>)/", "<div id=test" . $i . ">$1</div>"
```